# Multiple prepared statements within class, getting error: Call to undefined function prepare()

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm trying to run the following queries within my "registration" class and I'm getting the **error:** `Call to undefined function prepare()`.

I seem to be using prepared statements incorrectly.  This is my first attempt at using them within a class, so maybe I'm missing something there.  I would really like to take out the second block of code and use `lastInsertId()`, but I couldn't get that to work, so any suggestions related to that are welcome as well.

```
try{
    $sql = $this->$db->prepare("INSERT INTO `user_accounts` (`account_email`) VALUES (:email);");
    $sql->bindValue(':email', $email);
    $sql->execute();
    //The following line is giving me the error.
    $sql_2 = $this->$db->prepare("SELECT `user_account_id_PK` FROM `user_accounts` WHERE `account_email` = :email2;");
    $sql_2->bindValue(':email2', $email);
    $sql_2->execute();
    $id = $sql_2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    $query  = $this->$db->prepare("INSERT INTO `users` (`username`, `password`, `email`, `ip`, `time`, `email_code`, `ua_id_FK`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) ");
    $query->bindValue(1, $username);
    $query->bindValue(2, $password);
    $query->bindValue(3, $email);
    $query->bindValue(4, $ip);
    $query->bindValue(5, $time);
    $query->bindValue(6, $email_code);
    $query->bindValue(7, $id);
    $query->execute();

    //mail($email, 'Please activate your account', "Hello " . $username. ",\r\nThank you for registering with us. Please visit the link below so we can activate your account:\r\n\r\nhttp://www.launchevergreen.com/activate.php?email=" . $email . "&email_code=" . $email_code . "\r\n\r\n-- Evergreen team");
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    die($e->getMessage());
}
```

Comment: That means that `$this->db` is undefined - check if you have properly initialised / injected into your class!

Comment: `$this->$db` is undefined

Comment: Always, when using $this with a property of a class, you need to remove the $ of the variable...just $this->db

Comment: I actually didn't know that.  Thank you so much for pointing that out!  I probably should've known that, but I'm still learning how to use classes.  That saved my day!  If you will make your comment an answer, I'll give you credit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you posted, I saw that only the second prepare contains a `$this->$db` and the two others are correctly using `$this->db`, but now, I see that you edited the question and all of them are containing the same mistake `$this->$db`.

So I assume that you added the $ to `$this->db` in your code

If you didn't change `$this->$db` to `$this->db` it won't work.

Comment: Yes, I misread @Gzregorz Oledzki's answer and edited my post in the wrong direction before reading your comment and realizing my error.  I botched this one.

Comment: Okey, then keep in mind that when using $this with a property of a class... you need to remove the $ from the variable. (e.g : $this->x and not $this->$x) .

But when using self or parent with a variable of the class (static variable) you don't remove it (self::$x, parent::$x )

Answer (score 4):

I am not an expert in PHP, but probably instead of...

```
$sql_2 = $this->$db->prepare
```

you are after

```
$sql_2 = $this->db->prepare
```

Comment: Fixed by using `$this->$db` everywhere?

Comment: I apologize, I actually misread your answer when you first gave it, and then had moved on to @Smoot Q's comment which clued me into what I was doing wrong, so I gave him the credit for the answer.  You were right on, I was just too thick headed to realize it.  Giving you an upvote to hopefully make up for my idiocy.

Answer (score 2):

Use `$this->db` instead of `$this->$db`.

Comment: $sql_2 = $this->db->prepare("SELECT `user_account_id_PK` FROM `user_accounts` WHERE `account_email` = :email2");